# System.Threading.Timer example to run and display seconds until you click a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having some issues creating an asp.net page using C#
When you first click a button it starts the display of seconds via a label control.
When you click the button again the seconds stop.

Currently my code does just prints 0 and stops:

```
System.Threading.Timer Timer;
bool endProcess = false;
int i = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 10, 10);
  Label1.Text = i.ToString();
  i++;
}

private void TimerCallback(object state)
{

  if (endProcess == true)
  {
    Timer.Dispose();
    return;
  }
}

public void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  endProcess = true;
}
```

Comment: currently it just shows 0 and stops

Answer (score 4):

You must set the `label.text=i.toString();` in `timecallback` function not in `page_load`

Answer (score 1):

For this to work in ASP.NET, you should not use System.Threading.Timer, because this runs on the server side and you need to have the client side updated periodically. You have afew options for a WEB based application.

Keep in mind that you do not push UI updates to a web browser, the web browser needs to pull or request the update. So, a naive solution would be to have the browser periodically do a postback to the web server to get the updated text for the label. Not a good solution, but I share this as the basic premise of the concept.

I think the best option would be to this entirely on the client side using a javascript timer and updating the DOM element with the new value. Take a look at the second and third example on this page
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp